# TikZ and Plots line under curve

Tags: tikz-pgf

We are supposed to do this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDVit.jpg
I made everything except red dots and this line from sin to x-axis

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    height=10cm,
    width=16cm,
    xmax=50,
    xmin=-50,
    ymin=-2.5,
    ymax=2.5,
    xtick= {-50,-40,-30,-20,-10,0,10,20,30,40,50},
    xlabel={$t$},
    ylabel={$x(t)$}]
    \addplot [domain=-360:360, samples=720,
     thick, blue , mark=o, mark size=1pt,] {sin(15*x)+cos(22.5*x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here is my code for this graph so i have dots but i dont know how to paint them red and i dont know how to make this lines under/over the curve so how to do that?

Comment: Hint: look up `ycomb` plot in the manual.

Comment: This seems to be an almost precise duplicate of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/542861/194703). You can use the answer there (one does not need three separate plots, though).

Comment: BTW, "We are supposed to do this" and the fact that two practically identical questions appear within less than a day: are these homework assignments? (If not you can ask this question to be reopened.)